# Joomla redirect to login page with correct redirection parameter after unsuccessful login 

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.5, joomla1.7, joomla1.6

I have integrated Joomla with a vBulletin and a CPG using jFusion .

I have set the login link of vB and CPG as http://fakesite.com/site/index.php?option=com_user&view=login&return=Zm9ydW0ucGhw , so that when a user logs into Joomla from that link , he will get redirected back to vB or CPG after a successful login .

This is happening correctly , but when I login with a wrong username and password , it just redirects back to vB or CPG without any warning, or prompting to try again .

I am using latest Joomla 1.5.x version .

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$un = $_POST['username'];
$pass = md5($_POST['password']);

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM melga_eveikals_lietotaji WHERE username='$un'AND password='$pass'");
if (mysql_num_rows($sql) == 0){
header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
}
```

Comment: I know that, but when I login after that , I lose the redirection .

Comment: header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);

Comment: I can understand the code , but I still lose redirection . There is a return parameter in the URL which needs to stay .

Comment: The code redirects to /index.php?option=com_user . It loses the return parameter .